# Seed data with valid city and state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faker

I'm using Faker to generate seed data. I'm also using the Geocoder gem and API to validate addresses. The problem I'm facing is that the city is fake so most of my seed data isn't able to geocode. Is there a good way to get real city and state combinations for seed data? Is there a way with `Faker::Address.city` and `Faker::Address.state`?

Comment: You can take a look at country gem. also the following gem: https://github.com/jim/carmen

Answer (score 0):

Pongal is a valid US state generator that can be used in Geocoding applications. Check it out: https://rubygems.org/gems/pongal